# SQL Update and replace substring

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a query in SQL that change all 'a' in string to 'b' in first_name column in name table.
Here is my columns name:
    first_name | list_name

Answer (score 52):

use `REPLACE()`

```
UPDATE tableName
SET first_name = REPLACE(first_name, 'a', 'b')
```

but remember that `REPLACE()` is case sensitive.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: is there another function that is not case sensitive ?, or a parameter we can pass to REPLACE ?

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE name SET first_name = REPLACE (first_name, 'a', 'b') WHERE blabla LIKE '%blabla%';
OR
UPDATE name SET first_name = REPLACE (first_name, 'a', 'b') WHERE blabla = 'blabla';
```