# Mysql replaces part of a text in the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The table (`images_list` is the name of the table) I have to update has over 500 rows with a certain link which I have to replace to a url connected to a local folder.

For example a field will contain  `www.google.com/img/test-more-text.gif` and this has to be replaced to `/image/test-more-text.gif`. The prefix link is exactly the same for each row, the only variable part is the image name (`test-more-text.gif` for example is the only variable part in the example given above)

I've looked up multiple tutorials but the only things I can find replace the complete field whereas I need to keep the suffix so to speak.

This image obviously has a different name aswell so I can't simply do

```
UPDATE images_list 
SET image_link = '/image/test-more-text.gif' 
WHERE image_link = 'www.google.com/img/test-more-text.gif'
```

I know how to lookup text with the `LIKE` statement but I've never had to update something like this before.

If anyone knows how to do this that would safe me a ton of work

Comment: Is there really a space at the beginning of the `image_link` value?

Comment: @barmar No sorry for the confusion, I edited it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334813/sql-update-and-replace-substring

Comment: @krycke I found that question already but it completely replaced the field, what I needed was to only replace a specific part like in the answer Barmar has given

Comment: I thought it replaced 'a' with 'b' as in Barmar's suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `REPLACE` function:

```
UPDATE images_list
SET image_link = REPLACE(image_link, 'www.google.com/img/', '/image/');
WHERE image_link LIKE 'www.google.com/img/%'
```